# Inserting Meta using jade Template engine

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to render

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

in my index page Html head

is this the correct solution

`meta(name="viewport",content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, `meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')` is correct!

When it doubt use http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/

Answer (score -1):

In my case i'm passing variables to jade template using

`res.render('index.jade', obj);`

Strangely when he passed the `meta` line syntax jade, not working. The solution was send the string without `<` and `>`, but with html sintax

example:

`var meta = 'meta property="og:video" content=" ' + decode + '"';`